# The expression « Ce que j’ai honte ! »

Tags: expressions

> Oh, **ce que j’ai honte !** Faisons comme si vous ne l’aviez pas vue, d’accord ?

It is easy to assume that this expression means « vous me faites rougir en parlant d’un sujet délicat pour moi », but I’m not sure how the construction « ce que ... » leads to such a meaning.

How does it compare with these two constructions:

> Comme c'est embarrassant !
>
> Quelle honte !

Comment: At first sight, I would say it has the exact same meaning than "Comme"...

Comment: @Random Finding out its meaning is one thing, but I'm just as curious about how this expression can be used in other instances. Merci.

Comment: So I may add : it has the same meaning and can be used in the exact same way :)

Comment: To me it seems like it could be a shortened version of “[Qu’est-ce] **que j’ai honte**” but I don’t even see how this longer construction (logically) leads to the meaning you describe, so that observation is clearly of no great help getting to the bottom of this (if there is, in fact, a bottom to be gotten to below: “C’est comme ça, mon ami/e!”).

Comment: @PapaPoule Other way round: “[Qu’est-ce que] j’ai honte” is the more modern form of “[ce que] j’ai honte”. It's the same phenomenon (but in this case less stigmatized) as the tendency for the reinforced interrogative pronouns to replace the complex relative pronouns: "Regarde [ce que] j'ai fait" -> "Regarde [qu'est-ce que] j'ai fait"

Comment: @Eauquidort PapaPoule I'm more than familiar with the following two constructions. "Qu'est-ce qu'elle est belle !" or "Qu'elle est belle !" So basically, is "Ce qu'elle est belle !" another variation to say more or less the same thing? Merci.

Comment: @Ahalone-zee Yes in this case, "*Ce qu'elle est belle*" has the exact meaning of "*Qu'est-ce qu'elle est belle*". It's a slightly less formal variation (I think). It's weird because orally I'd say it's less formal but written the it feels like a more proper way of saying it.

Comment: @Eauquidort That's interesting, but how do you know which way it is ? I'm curious, I also thought it was the other way around.

Comment: It's not that uncommon. I'm surprised you haven't heard it already. Maybe it's because it's at the same time casual, but not used at all by young people. And even then most people prefer "*Qu'est-ce que ...*" over "*Ce que ...*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ***Ce que j'ai honte !*** is equivalent to Random's comment ***comme j'ai honte !***. See the [tlfi ce entry](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ce) (II.B.1.) .The person speaking is personally embarrassed. (**I'm so ashamed!**)
- With ***comme c'est embarrassant !***, the person speaking is telling something is embarrassing but might not be affected personally. (**How embarrassing!**)
- Finally, with ***quelle honte !***, the person speaking is upset by someone else's behavior. (**What a shame/disgrace!**)